# Handling timeout with Hystrix

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, hystrix

I am trying to implement Hystrix in my spring boot application. I am using **@HystrixCommand** annotation on method which calls a service  A using RestTemplate. I have noticed that Hystrix invokes if there is failure while calling the service A, but I want to invoke it only if there is a time out. 
Service A does the validation, and if there is any parameter missing it respond back with 404. I have read a lot by googling it, but seems there is no easy way (like configuring the properties). Does anybody has idea? Appreciate your help.

Comment: You can use `ignoreExceptions` on the annotation for anything you're not interested in?

Comment: yes, But in case if there are many exception, is there any way just to allow only few of them and ignore rest of the exception.